# jquery validation remote validation rule depending if body has a class name

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery validate plugin to validate my form.

One field has a remote rule which checks to make sure that the value entered isn't already in the database.  This rule is used by 2 different pages and they both have a different body class which identifies them to the validation rule.

The problem is that it's failing on the depends rule so the remote validation never happens. If i remove the depends part, the remote validation works.

What is wrong with the depends part to make it fail?

```
$("form").validate({
        errorClass: "authError",
        errorElement: "div",
        rules: {
            some_field: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    depends: function() {
                        return $('body').hasClass('some-class');
                    },
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/check.php',
                    data: {
                        'something': $('#some_field').val()
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't with the `data:` parameter? It needs to be a function so that it gets the current value of the field. You're using the value at page load time.

Comment: If i take out the depends rule, the remote validation works. I only want to use the remote rule if the body has a certain class

Comment: I don't believe that it works. I think it should be `'somethng': function() { return $('#some_field').val(); }`

Comment: Just a typo...it does work

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it like so

```
some_field: {
    required: true,
        remote: {
            param: {
                url: '/check.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'something': $('#some_field').val()
                }
            },
            depends: function() {
                return $('body').hasClass('some-class');
            }
        }
    },
```